# PHP PDO apostrophe

Tags: php, pdo, apostrophe

I have a problem to execute a Stored Procedure (FIREBIRD) from php:

```
$sqlSP="select record_created,record_updated from SP_IMPORT_CRM_SELECTIE (11, 'AC015612','".$tester."'..............
```

When $tester containts this symbol '  I have a problem..

how can I fix that?

Comment: Sanitize the param, use `addslashes`. Check http://us1.php.net/manual/es/function.addslashes.php

Comment: @sal00m **never** use `addslashes()` to sanitize database data. PDO has prepared statements for the purpose.

Comment: Please specify which database you are connecting to because escaping characters varies between RDBMSs. It is also important to note that you are not using PDO to it's full extent with your current query.

Comment: You're correct @Pekka웃, forget my comment :S. The correct way is using prepared statements

Comment: I am wondering (sometimes) why such questions *still*  get answers.

Answer (score 11):

Essentially, you need to escape the string before using it within a query.

The best way to do this is through the use of PDO prepared statements:

```
$sqlSP="select record_created,record_updated from SP_IMPORT_CRM_SELECTIE (11, 'AC015612',:tester)";
$ps=$dbhandle->prepare($sqlSP);
$ps->bindParam(':tester',$tester,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$ps->execute();
```

(assuming that `$dbhandle` is your PDO object)

Comment: Sweet mercy this answer is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Try binding the parameters, take a look at the prepare method.

[PHP.net PDO::Prepare](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)